# .htaccess redirect subdomains with subfolder to root, exclude subdomains themself

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm sorry if this was asked before but I couldn't get an answer.

I would like to 301 redirect subdomains with subfolder to root, but to ignore subdomains:

```
test.example.com -> test.example.com
test.example.com/folder1/folder2 -> example.com/folder1/folder2
anyother.example.com -> anyother.example.com
anyother.example.com/folder1/folder2 -> example.com/folder1/folder2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%1/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

1. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.` makes sure rule doesn't fire for `www.example.com`
2. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(example\.com)$` to make sure we use it for sub domain
3. `^(.+)$` in `RewriteRule` to make sure we don't redirect landing page of sub domains.